# Android - How to Display Large Text in Notification

Tags: android, notifications

I need to implement a code for displaying large text with 200 characters in Notifications. Here i used following code but it shows single line.

```
       Intent notificationIntent;
       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pintent);
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Notifications are more flexible in size and layout in Android 4.1 Check doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: It's called `Big Style Notification` and go to this [link](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/) for example

Answer (score 2):

You can choose from different styles to use for the notification builder:

In your case I would use the NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle. More details can be found [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html)

Don't forget to import v4 support when using this.

Answer (score 1):

In my application, notification message is static but can't show all sentense.
I solved with subText properties of notification.

```
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle("Job Tracker Application")
.setContentText("GPS is turned off.")
.setSubText("Please turn on in the settings.")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent) 
.setAutoCancel(true)
.build();
```

Another notification sample have show under the blogs.
http://www.objc.io/issue-11/android-notifications.html
https://capdroid.wordpress.com/tag/android-notification/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm

Answer (score 1):

You add a style for the the large text.

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_SYNC)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_sync)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
```